# Keystrokes in Winforms app causing window to close unexpectedly

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a strange issue that has arisen recently:

Whenever I enter text, even a single character, into a textbox in any Form in my application it causes the form and its parent to close. I've checked for the following so far:

- Errant/mis-assigned event handlers that may be interpreting a keystroke as a Form cancel
- I am using keypreview in several windows but debugging shows this to not be a cause
- Happens in any form of the application
- Happens even with brand new text boxes dropped on the form
- Tried removing the WithEvents declaration from text box declarations (VB.NET)
- The result is DialogResult.Cancel when I break the code after Show or ShowDialog
- The forms do not use AcceptButton or CancelButton properties (set to none)
- Note: I am modifying a large codebase with a lot of code that I have yet to touch

What else could be causing this strange behavior?

Comment: Just a shot, but i would try wiring up a FormClosing event and putting a break point there.  You could review the stack trace to see how you got there.

Comment: Mike_G: You were right on. Turn your comment into an answer and i'll upvote you. Slaks got the checkmark already though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Press Ctrl+D, E (Debug, Exceptions) and tell Visual Studio to break whenever any exception is thrown, then see if there are any exceptions at work.
- Press Ctrl+D, N (Debug, New Breakpoint, Break at Function) and set a breakpoint on `System.Windows.Form.OnClosing`, then look at the call stack.  (Alternatively, override `OnClosing` in the main form, then set a breakpoint in it)

Comment: Yup. i actually had the same thought right after i posted this question. Breaking in the Form Closing handler allowed me to see enough of the call stack to identify a timer that was checking the state of the application cursor and using a goto to error out, be silently closing the app, when the cursor was null. i wonder how far this Rube Goldberg invention is spread. Still not sure how in the heck a text change could be affecting the message queue that much...

Answer (score 1):

The DialogResult of the button was set to 'Cancel" by accident. After change back to default value "None", the problem is solved. This is my story.